# Firebase and SwiftUI | Saving profile data

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and Firebase and trying to create a budgeting app. I'm having trouble saving the user data. I'm using SwiftUI (not Storyboard) and I also have AppDelegate and SceneDelegate.

The way the app works is that it asks the user to create the profile (email and password) and then the user is being created in firebase. Afterwards it redirects the user to a second screen that requires the following data (see the picture):

My questions are:

- How to I upload a photo to the firebase?
- How do I associate the photo and the other data (age, City, etc.) to the created user?

I am searching for a solution online for a few days already but everything online is either using Storyboard or very old version of Swift. Furthermore, I've already created the user but I don't know how do I associate the data on this screen with the created user.

Here is the code of the screen shown above:

```
struct RegistrationProfileDataView: View {

//@Binding var show : Bool
@State var firstName = ""
@State var lastName = ""
@State var age = ""
@State var location = ""
@State var picker = false
@State var loading = false
@State var imagedata : Data = .init(count: 0)
@State var alert = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Group {
            Group {
                Text("Welcome")
                    .font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.title/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                Text("Please finish your registration")
                Button(action: {
                    self.picker.toggle()
                }) {
                    if self.imagedata.count == 0 {
                        Image("ChangeProfPhoto").resizable().frame(width: 109, height: 109)
                    }
                    else {
                        Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: self.imagedata)!).resizable().renderingMode(.original).frame(width: 109, height: 109).clipShape(Circle())
                    }
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                .padding(.top, 20)
            }
            .padding(.leading, 25)
            TextField("First Name", text: self.$firstName)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 45.0)
                .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.lightGray, lineWidth: 1))
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
            TextField("Last Name", text: self.$lastName)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 45.0)
                .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.lightGray, lineWidth: 1))
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
            TextField("Age", text: self.$age)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 45.0)
                .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.lightGray, lineWidth: 1))
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
            TextField("City", text: self.$location)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 45.0)
                .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.lightGray, lineWidth: 1))
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Action@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                Text("Link a Bank Account")
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 45.0)
            .background(Capsule().fill(Color.lightGray))
            .padding(.horizontal, 25.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 15.0)
        }
        Spacer()
        Group {
            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Action@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                Text("Finish")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 45.0)
            .background(Capsule().fill(Color.blue))
            .padding(.horizontal, 25.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 15.0)
            .shadow(color: ColorManager.blueButton.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 2.0, y: 2.0)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A video tutorial or an article suggestion would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase documentation is very good and is all modern Swift code. It's not really reliant on UI code (either SwiftUI or Storyboards).

Regarding SwiftUI, in general, you probably want to do your networking calls outside of a view, perhaps in an ObservableObject:

```
class FirebaseManager : ObservableObject {
  func uploadImage(imageData: Data) {
    //do upload
  }
}
```

You could store this on your view by doing:

```
@StateObject private var firebaseManager = FirebaseManager()
```

To upload an image, you would do something like (this is taken almost directly from the Firebase documentation -- https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files):

```
// Create a reference to the file you want to upload
let profileImageRef = storageRef.child("images/\(userID)/rivers.jpg")

// Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
let uploadTask = profileImageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
  guard let metadata = metadata else {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    return
  }
  // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
  let size = metadata.size
  // You can also access to download URL after upload.
  profileImageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
    guard let downloadURL = url else {
      // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      return
    }
  }
}
```

Note that on the first line I used `userID` -- you could get a reference to your logged in user by doing:

```
guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
  return
}
```

Finally, regarding the question of "How do I associate the photo and the other data (age, City, etc.) to the created user?", you'll need to choose either Firestore or Realtime Database. Both have great documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs in modern Swift.

Create a function inside `FirebaseManager` to upload the data and just make sure that you're associating it with the same user ID as your profile image (as detailed above).

Comment: Just my $0.02, but I disagree that the Firebase documentation is "very good". Yes, they provide Swift and Objective-C, but I've given them tons of feedback about out-of-date pages, mistakes, etc. They still don't have their code using the SwiftUI lifecycle. They still mostly talk about CocoaPods instead of Swift Package manager. I'm really disappointed that Google's documentation is so poor: disconnected, out-of-date, hard to navigate, etc. You *can* get information out of it, but it's a bit of a hard slog.